# How implement ReceiveCustomWebHooks in WebApi.Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, webhooks

I am following this link to implement webhooks between two systems with WebApi

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/sending-webhooks-with-asp-net-webhooks-preview/

The problem is that the receiving API is developed in .NET Core and I don't see the support for config.InitializeReceiveCustomWebHooks(); inside the startup.

The code in .Net Framework is like this:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    // Web API configuration and services
    
    // Web API routes
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
    
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
    
    // Load Web API controllers and Azure Storage store
    config.InitializeCustomWebHooks();
    config.InitializeCustomWebHooksAzureStorage();
    config.InitializeCustomWebHooksApis();
    config.InitializeReceiveCustomWebHooks();
}
```

Does anyone know how to implement it in .NET Core?

Thank you

Comment: When I say at the end .NET, I mean .NET core

Comment: From[Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebHooks.Receivers](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebHooks.Receivers/1.0.0-preview2-final) we can see, the package is  deprecated .

Comment: What do you think is the best way to implement webhooks in .Net Core?

My architecture is based on an API (.Net Framework), and I need that when one of the methods is called, the event is fired, and another different API (.NET core) picks it up